# Redirect from Mozilla Firefox to Android app - Deep Linking

Tags: android, firefox, redirect, deep-linking

I use an intent filter to allow deep linking to an activity of my application.
Like in the example given below:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

The redirection to my app works fine with Google Chrome and the Android Browser but when i use Firefox, the problem is that Firefox launches a new instance of my app, instead of redirecting me to the already launched instance of the app. Moreover the new launhed app seems to be running through Firefox.

The senario is the following:
1) I launch my app. If the user has forgot his credentials i send him an email.
2) The user goes to his email app.
3) In the email i sent to the user, there is an account activation link which also redirects him back to the application.

What could be wrong with Firefox?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is probably a problem / bug with firefox, as it also happens with other apps

Comment: I'm getting the same issue too! One solution I've found to work is to set the activity's launch mode to `singleTask`, but this messes up other interactions with the activity within my app - really annoying!

Answer (score 0):

According to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44592385/6444297), Firefox implements a less invasive experience to the user. When an url is opened which has a deep link to an app, the url bar displays a page action with a little Android head. Clicking on this one will open the link with an Android activity other than a browser.
The behavior of the Android browser and Chrome you observed and made your expectation.